# Control and observability of Clifford algebra and quaternion valued systems?

Tags: differential-equations, oc.optimization-and-control, quaternions, clifford-algebras

Good evening everybody, I'm asking you if there is a mathematical theory about control and observability of differential systems within the quaternionic and Clifford (geometric) algebras. And if so, please provide me some literature. Thank you.
H. Banouh.